# is it possible to send message by WebSphere MQ and receive the message by msnq

Tags: message-queue, msmq, ibm-mq

I know that this question is little strange .. but this is my first time i using any queue on my code .. so sorry

some application sending me a messages by using WebSphere MQ. 
And i want to receive the messages by using simple know msnq.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

No. But IBM gives its MQ away for development use so you can have the full MQ server on your laptop, and several QMgrs if you want.  You can also have the MQ client installed with the server or separately.

For more information on getting started with MQ, click on the [websphere-mq](/questions/tagged/websphere-mq) tag and then click "Learn More."  You will then find links to all the downloads and manuals.  There are plenty of code samples installed with the server or the client.

[image]